# Error in as.xts - could not find function "as.xts" trouble installing tseries package?

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to R but have used the as.xts function previously where I had to first install a tseries package:

```
install.packages("tseries")
library(tseries)
```

whereas now when I try re-do the same, it seems like the `tseries` package is not working properly and when I run the `as.xts` for example

```
returns <- as.xts(aapl[, -1], order.by = as.Date(aapl$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

I get an error

> Error in as.xts - could not find function "as.xts"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do `library(xts)` to load `xts` as I don't think package `tseries` has a formal Depends: on package `xts`.

Comment: that fixed it! thank you